# Error with copying contents from one file to another - random letter appears at the end

Tags: c, file, io, stdio, fgetc

This program takes reads a file `file.txt` that contains few lines of text, reverses that text and prints it out to a temporary file `tempFile.txt`. After this, the program copies the reversed text from the temporary file to the original file. And lastly, the program deletes the temporary file.

However, after the text is copied from file to another, a letter **ÿ** randomly appeared at the end of the file. Why did this happen and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Note that when you seek to the end, there is no character to read.  You need `fseek(fp1, -1L, SEEK_END)` so you can read the last character in the file.

Answer (score 2):

It's always the same bug: **You cannot test for EOF until *after* you attempted input**.

With this in mind, assume the file is empty then think through your code. Can you now see where the bug is?

You should rewrite your loop as

```
 while ((a = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) {
   fputc(a, fp2);
 }
```

The "funny" character appears because you hit EOF, store it in a character, and write it. Usually `EOF` has the value -1 and you get an extra 0xFF character, sometimes appearing as "ÿ".